# Create js npm plugin with use fn (like chai)

Tags: javascript, npm, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to create a JavaScript npm where you can set a variable within the plugin, so that when you import the plugin from another page, the variable is still set.

For example: 
//plugin.js

```
var pizza
export default (topping)=>pizza = topping
export function getPizza(){return pizza}
```

Then, in any application I'm building, I could use the plugin like so.

//index.js

```
import setPizza from 'plugin'
setPizza('peppers')
```

//otherfile.js

```
import {getPizza} from 'plugin'
alert(getPizza())
```

The key is that I want to be able to reference the plugin, and not any particular file, to get whatever the last pizza value that was set.

Comment: You're trying to create a JavaScript Node Package Manager? Anyway, what exactly are you having trouble with? You haven't asked a question - simply stated some things that seem very doable.

Comment: Im trying to make an npm plugin. It seems like an easy question, but when I create the above implementation, it doesn't work. I don't know what Im suposed to do

Comment: Are you aware that Node.js does not currently support ES6 module loader syntax, and instead uses an implentation of CommonJS? Are you using Babel, or an equivalent transpiler? Are there any errors?